# IIS 7 Creating New Website

Tags: iis-7, web

I'm trying to learn IIS and I'm creating a basic website locally on my computer. Here's what I did...

1. Open IIS 7 Manager
2. Right Click "Sites"
3. Click "Add Website"
4. Set "Site Name"
5. Set "Physical Path" with a file called "default.htm" (c:\inetput\site1)
6. Set "Host name:" to site1.com
7. Click OK

When I try to go to my new site1.com (not www, I've yet to set that binding) I keep getting a message saying that the server "is taking too long to respond".

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. - I'm using Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

site1.com probably isn't resolving since there's no DNS entry for it.  You'll need to add an entry in your `hosts` file for site1.com or try accessing it directly by the IP address you assigned.

Comment: I just updated by question...I'm on Windows 8..Does that change anything?